# Can not connect outlets to a generic class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

It seems like there is a bug in xcode that prevents it from 'recognizing' classes that contain generic declarations.

Take this example class declaration :

```
@interface ABEBaseParseQueryViewController<CellType: UITableViewCell *, Object: id> : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, ABEDatasourceResponder>
```

If I were to manually type out an outlet declaration inside the header file :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titleField;
```

The dot in the sidebar that signifies that is an unconected outlet does not appear. Furthermore, when trying to set the file's owner to this class in IB, I do not get any autocompletion, making it seem like xcode does not 'recognize' the class at all. I can not connect outlets to the file even if I manually set the file owner.

This problem is fixed if I remove the generic declaration from the class. (the circle in the sidebar reappears and I can connect outlets again)

Anyone else been having this problem? For now I can just remove the generic declaration, connect the outlets and put it back, but that seems like a bad workaround.

This is xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. Once you have a generic (as in this example):

```
ABEBaseParseQueryViewController<CellType: UITableViewCell *, Object: id>
```

that class is no longer an option for **Custom Class** in **Interface Builder**.

You can circumvent this limitation, however by first creating and picking:

```
ABEBaseParseQueryViewController
```

[image: Pick ABEBaseParseQueryViewController before using generics]

in Interface Builder, and *later on* changing your `.h` to become

```
ABEBaseParseQueryViewController<CellType: UITableViewCell *, Object: id>
```

Note that you can no longer even pick that generic **Custom Class** in **Interface Builder** at this time.